# How can I call a function that is stored as a variable from a python file that is also stored as a variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-importlib

I can import a python script using import_module. But, how can I call a function stored as a variable from that script? I've previously used getattr to work with dictionaries stored as variables, but I don't think this same method works with functions. Here's an example that does not currently work:

```
from importlib import import_module

file_list = ['file1','file2']
func_list = ['func1','func2']

for file in file_list:
  test_file = import_module(file)
  for func in func_list:
    from test_file import func
```

file1:

```
def func1():
  ...

def func2():
  ...
```

file2:

```
def func1():
  ...

def func2():
  ...
```

Comment: The way you're doing it, `getattr(test_file, func)` should get you the function (the `getattr(obj, 'prop')` function is essentially syntactic longhand for `obj.prop`), which you can then call in the usual way. But why do you need to be doing this dynamically, and not via normal `import` statements? There's very rarely a good reason to do something this complicated.

Comment: The common use case for dynamic import is to implement some kind of plugin system. I have a project which does this.

Comment: I'm creating a PYQT5 GUI test program that is tab-based. Users choose the tabs they want to be shown beforehand and then the tabs' settings get loaded within a loop. Each tab represents a unique test with unique settings. Then, when the user selects RUN, each test is run in order. This is where I'm running into this problem. I wanted each of the tabs to be loaded/run dynamically like this, but it is proving to be quite difficult.

Comment: @JohnHerwig Dynamic imports and function calls is probably not the best implementation for this. Have you considered just using regular OO programming (specifically, classes and polymorphism)?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy using getattr does get the function. I was using it incorrectly. Thank you. I have been going down this dynamic road for a while. I was originally trying to make it easy for future users to create new tests. That is why I chose this dynamic method in the first place, but I may look into more OO methods if I continue to get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can import a python script using import_module.

When you do this, the result is a *module object* - just the same as an `import` statement provides.

> from test_file import func

The reason this doesn't work is because it is looking for a `test_file` module - and it cares about module names as they appear in `sys.path`, not about your local variable names.

Fortunately, since you already have the module object, you presumably realized you could access the contents normally, as attributes, e.g. `test_file.func`.

> I've previously used getattr to work with dictionaries stored as variables, but I don't think this same method works with functions

I'm not quite sure what you mean here. Attributes are attributes, whether they're plain data, functions, classes or anything else. `test_file` is a thing that has a `func` attribute, therefore `getattr(test_file, 'func')` gets that attribute.

The remaining issue is the variable-variables problem - you don't really want to be creating a name for that result dynamically. So yes, you can store that in a dict, if you want. But frankly it's easier to *just use the `module` object*. Unless perhaps for some reason you need/want to "trim" the contents and only expose a limited interface (for some other client); but you can't avoid loading the whole module. `from X import Y` *does that anyway*.

The `module` object that you got from the dynamic import is already working as a namespace, which you need here anyway because you're importing multiple modules that have overlapping attribute names.

tl;dr: if you want to call a function from that imported module, just do it the same way that you would have if you had imported the module (not a name `from` that module) normally. We can, for example, put the imported modules in a list:

```
modules = [import_module(f) for f in filenames]
```

and then call the appropriate method by looking it up within the appropriate module object:

```
modules[desired_module_id].desired_func()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was using getattr incorrectly and this answer helped me to understand more of the behind-the-scenes mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

basically You would run this code in a separate file and where it says `the_file_where_this_is_needed.py` You would insert the file where You want these import statement to be. (also probably You can run this code in the very file). it will be sort of like hardcoding but automatic

```
file_list = ['file1', 'file2']
func_list = ['func1', 'func2']


with open('the_file_where_this_is_needed.py', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

string = ''
for file in file_list:
    for func in func_list:
        string += f'from {file} import {func}\n'

data = string + data

with open('the_file_where_this_is_needed.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: `from file import func` works with the literal names `'file'` and `'func'`, not with variables even if the variables are in scope. This is why `importlib` exists in the first place: for dynamic imports.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy well I did not take that into consideration :p, thanks for the information about importlib though

Comment: @Matiiss I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named file" using your code.

Comment: @JohnHerwig yup that is an issue, however I came up with a rather obscure solution and will present to You in a moment

Comment: @JohnHerwig so I made a few edits and it is possible to use my code but... it may not be the best way to do so since it is almost unnecessary but this works